# PHP doesn't work in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Beginner's question, so please bear with me.

I installed XAMPP under Windows XP, and PHP seems to work: when I click "phpinfo()" in http://localhost/xampp/ the complete list of settings is shown. However, when I check file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php I get an error message saying "Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(". Apparently the PHP code in this file is not being executed. Any ideas?

TIA
Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access http://localhost/xampp/index.php then your request is processed by apache web server, which invokes php interpreter.

Accessing the same file directly (via file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php) does not go through the apache web server and that is why no php interpreter is invoked.